# Approximating Differential Equations Using Difference Equations/The $z$-Transform.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, approximation, intuition, z-transform

I'm aware that difference equations and the $z$-Transform method can be used to approximate differential equations but I'm wondering how exactly it does this as I don't have a clue? All I've come across is the formula 
$x_a(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_nq(t-nT)$.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: To get any kind of useful answer you need to elaborate on the extent of your knowledge on the topic. What do you know about differential equations, difference equations, methods of solving them etc

Comment: And the formula you provided: where did you find it and what do $q,T$ stand for?

Comment: I'm aware that differential equations are solved using Laplace Transforms and that difference equations are solved using $z$-Transforms. I'm also aware that differential equations can be approximated through the use of difference equations and hence the $z$-Transform method but what I don't understand is how it can do this. As for the formula, I really do not understand it. I obtained it from 'Theory and Application of the $z$-Transform Method' by E.I. Jury and all it states is that $q(t) = L^{-1}[Q(s)]$. Thanks!